# HSpec Nothing expectation failing to compile

Tags: haskell, hspec

I'm learning Haskell and I've written this function:

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead (x:xs) = Just x
```

I'm now trying to test it with HSpec:

```
import Test.Hspec

main :: IO ()
main = hspec spec

spec :: Spec
spec =

  describe "safeHead" $
    it "should return Nothing for empty list" $
      safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing
```

But that fails to compile:

```
Error:(14, 19) ghc: No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘shouldBe’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
      instance Eq a => Eq (GHC.Real.Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in ‘ghc-prim-0.4.0.0:GHC.Classes’
      ...plus 31 others
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘it "should return Nothing for empty list"
       $ safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing’
    In the expression:
      describe "safeHead"
      $ it "should return Nothing for empty list"
        $ safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing
```

I have also tried this:

```
safeHead :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead (x:xs) = Just x
```

But that still fails with:

```
Error:(14, 19) ghc: No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘shouldBe’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Either a b)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
      instance Eq Data.Monoid.All -- Defined in ‘Data.Monoid’
      instance forall (k :: BOX) (f :: k -> *) (a :: k).
               Eq (f a) =>
               Eq (Data.Monoid.Alt f a)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Monoid’
      ...plus 43 others
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘it "should return Nothing for empty list"
       $ safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing’
    In the expression:
      describe "safeHead"
      $ it "should return Nothing for empty list"
        $ safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing
```

I don't know what's the problem here. If I try other tests like these, it compiles fine:

```
    it "should return the head" $ do
      safeHead [1] `shouldBe` Just 1
      safeHead [2,3,4,5,6,1] `shouldBe` Just 2
```

So, it's something about `Nothing` itself, that it cannot be compared by equals? How do you assert that something returns `Nothing` then? Or is my function too generic?

SIDE NOTE:
I've seen a similar error with this function:

```
palindrome :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
palindrome xs = xs ++ reverse xs
```

When trying to test for empty lists:

```
palindrome [] `shouldBe` []
```

Which fails with:

```
Error:(26, 21) ghc: No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘shouldBe’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
      instance Eq a => Eq (GHC.Real.Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Eq Ordering -- Defined in ‘ghc-prim-0.4.0.0:GHC.Classes’
      ...plus 32 others
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: palindrome [] `shouldBe` []
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘do { palindrome [] `shouldBe` [] }’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘it
         "should turn a list into a palindrome, so it reads same both forwards and backwards"
       $ do { palindrome [] `shouldBe` [] }’
```

Comment: try `safeHead ([] :: [Int]) `shouldBe` Nothing`

Comment: That worked! What's the reason behind it? You are coercing the parameter to have a type? Like a cast?

Comment: @Zeta gave an really good answer to that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, it's something about Nothing itself, that it cannot be compared by equals?

What's `Nothing`'s type? It's `Nothing :: Maybe a`. And GHC doesn't like `a` in this context: "The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous". After all, `shouldBe` takes anything that can be compared with `(==)` and shown. And `Maybe a` is an instance of `Eq` if `a` is an instance of `Eq`. GHC can't possibly know *which* `a` you want to use, so you need to specify it by hand:

```
  describe "safeHead" $
    it "should return Nothing for empty list" $
      safeHead [] `shouldBe` (Nothing :: Maybe Int)
```

That's not coercion, you're just making clear *which* of all possible types you want to use. Other examples:

```
  describe "safeHead" $
    it "should return Nothing for empty list" $ do
      safeHead [] `shouldBe` (Nothing :: Maybe Int)
      safeHead [] `shouldBe` (Nothing :: Maybe ())
      safeHead [] `shouldBe` (Nothing :: Maybe Integer)
      safeHead [] `shouldBe` (Nothing :: Maybe Char)
```