# Writing a function from definitions?

Tags: function, haskell, types, definition

First off, I would like to make you all aware that I'm very new to Haskell, so to increase knowledge etc, I've been trying out questions and I'm pretty stuck on one. I think I'm nearly there but some more experienced advice would be appreciated. Here's the question:

A sporting team is represented by it's name and the amount of points they scored in their last games like so `("Newcastle",[3,3,3,0])`. This data is modelled by the type definitions:

```
type TName = String
type Points = [Int]
type Team = (TName,Points)
```

From this I have to define the following function that orders one team higher than another if their points sum is greater:

```
sortPoints :: [Team] -> [Team]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
sortPoints :: [Team] -> [Team]
sortPoints [_,()] -> []
sortPoints [_,(x:xs)] = sum[x|x<-xs]
```

Once I get to here, I'm not too sure how to go about adding the conditions to check the points sum, any pointers would be greatly appreciated as I'm still coming to terms with a lot of Haskell features.

Comment: have a look at [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=compare) and search for: `sortBy`, `compare`, `on` and `snd` - you can puzzle those together to get exactly what you want (by puzzle together I really am talking about *composing* )

Comment: @Carsten: That could have been an answer. :D

Comment: @Zeta yours has a bit more info though ;) (+1)

Comment: @Carsten: Still, this is getting into a habit: you [post a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612654/hspec-nothing-expectation-failing-to-compile/30617137#comment49292172_30612654), and I write a community wiki answer based on that comment :D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: This post is written in literate Haskell. You can save it as `Team.lhs` and try it. That being said, it's basically a longer version of Carsten's comment. If you still try to figure things out, use hoogle and look for the functions, although it's fine if you manage things with `sortBy` solely first.

---

First of all, we're going to work on lists, so you want to import `Data.List`.

```
> module Team where
> import Data.List
```

It contains a function called `sortBy`:

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

The first argument of `sortBy` should be a function that compares two elements of your list and returns

- `LT` if the first is less than the second,
- `EQ` if the both are equal,
- `GT` if the first is greater than the second.

So we need something that that takes two teams and returns their ordering:

```
> -- Repeating your types for completeness
> type TName  = String
> type Points = [Int]
> type Team   = (TName, Points)
>
> compareTeams :: Team -> Team -> Ordering
```

Now, you want to compare teams based on their sum of their points. You don't need their name, so you can capture just the second part of the pair:

```
> compareTeams (_, s1) (_, s2) =
```

We need the sum of the points, so we define `sum1` and `sum2` to be the respective sums of the teams:

```
>       let sum1 = sum s1
>           sum2 = sum s2
```

Now we can compare those sums:

```
        in if sum1 < sum2 
             then LT
             else if sum1 == sum2 
                     then EQ
                     else GT
```

However, that's rather verbose, and there's already a function that has type `Ord a => a -> a -> Ordering`. It's called `compare` and part of the `Prelude`:

```
>       in sum1 `compare` sum2
```

That's a lot more concise. Now we can define `sortTeams` easily:

```
> sortTeams :: [Team] -> [Team]
> sortTeams = sortBy compareTeams
```

And that's it, we're done!

---

Fine, I lied, we're not 100% done. The module `Data.Ord` contains a function called `comparing` that's rather handy:

```
comparing :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Ordering
comparing f x y = f x `compare` f y -- or similar
```

Together with `snd` and `sum` you can define `sortTeams` in a single line:

```
sortTeams = sortBy (comparing $ sum . snd)
```

The alternative `on` mentioned by Carsten is `on` from `Data.Function`:

```
sortTeams = sortBy (compare `on` sum . snd)
```

Comment: There should be more Literate Haskell answers like this one :)