# How to resolve type ambiguity in this unit test

Tags: haskell, option-type, hunit

I can't figure out how to annotate the mylast3 test properly:

```
import Test.HUnit

mylast :: [a] -> Maybe a
mylast [] = Nothing
mylast [x] = Just x
mylast (_:xs) = mylast xs

testsMyLast =
  [TestCase $ assertEqual "mylast1" (Just 1) $ mylast [1],
   TestCase $ assertEqual "mylast2" (Just 'b') $ mylast "ab",
   TestCase $ assertEqual "mylast3" Nothing $ mylast []  <== how to test this correctly?
   ]

main = do runTestTT $ TestList testsMyLast
```

I'm getting the following error pointing at the line "TestCase $ assertEqual "mylast3":

> No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of assertEqual The type
>   variable a0 is ambiguous

Comment: `$ myLast ([] :: [Int])` might do the trick in making the type unambiguous

Comment: Thanks! Could you post this as answer so that I mark the question as answered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HSpec Nothing expectation failing to compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612654/hspec-nothing-expectation-failing-to-compile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the list `[]` does not have any members, it can only be deduced from type inference that `[]` is of type `[a]`.

For a list to be "showable" it must be an instance of the typeclass `Show`. A list is only an instance of `Show` if the members of the list are also instances of `Show`.

But the type checker can't deduce the type of `[]` to a more specific type than `[a]`. We *cannot* know if `a` is an instance of `Show` so we also *cannot* know if `[a]` is in turn an instance of `Show`.

If we simply **annotate a specific type** `([] :: [Int])` there will be no error!

This is because we know that `Int` is an instance of `Show` and therefore `[Int]` is also an instance of `Show`. Now the compiler can infer the necessary information to print the list!